# How to run a python3 installed package?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I installed a package to python3.7 but when I try to run the executable its getting invoked from python2.7 and it fails as its not present in python3.7

```
$ sudo -H pip install blobbycompanyconnect --index https://pypi.company.com/simple --user
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.company.com/simple, https://pypi.company.com/simple
Requirement already satisfied: blobbycompanyconnect in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from blobbycompanyconnect) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock==3.0.12 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from blobbycompanyconnect) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from blobbycompanyconnect) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backoff<2.0.0,>=1.8.0 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete<2.0.0,>=1.6.0 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyotp==2.3.0 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.18.4 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyaml==19.4.1 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (19.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->blobbycompanyconnect) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<2,>=0.23; python_version == "3.7" in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from argcomplete<2.0.0,>=1.6.0->trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.18.4->trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.18.4->trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.18.4->trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.18.4->trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyaml==19.4.1->trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /private/var/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.23; python_version == "3.7"->argcomplete<2.0.0,>=1.6.0->trovecompanyconnect<3.0,>=2.0->blobbycompanyconnect) (3.1.0)
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Error:-

```
$ blobbycompanyconnect 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/blobbycompanyconnect", line 6, in <module>
    from blobbycompanyconnect.cli import main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/blobbycompanyconnect/cli.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .companyconnect import get_cli_creds
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/blobbycompanyconnect/companyconnect.py", line 5, in <module>
    from trovecompanyconnect.companyconnect_auth_api import companyconnectAuthApi, AppToApp, BOLTENV
ImportError: No module named trovecompanyconnect.companyconnect_auth_api
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project runs on 2.7. I don't know if you use a virtual environment, maybe you should upgrade python there or on your IDE mostly on the right bottom you can see your python version check it.